# Cannot change parameter in C# WebApi async method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, default-parameters

first post here.
I have a problem with default parameter in ASP.Net WebApi. When I do the request without year and month in route it uses defaults "0". But when i try to change this default values in action to actual date it keeps the "0" value. I tryed with default parameters as

```
int? year = null, int? month = null
```

but doesn't work either.

Controller RoutePrefix

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Wallets")]
```

And actual Action

```
[Route("{id:int}/{year:int?}/{month:int?}")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Wallet))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetWallet(int id, int year = 0, int month = 0)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    Wallet wallet = await db.Wallets.FindAsync(id);
    if (wallet == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (wallet.UserId != userId)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    if(year == 0)
    {
        year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }

    if(month == 0)
    {
        month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    }

    wallet.Expenses = wallet.Expenses.Where(e => e.Date.Month == month && e.Date.Year == year).ToList();

    return Ok(wallet);
}
```

Request is

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/Wallets/16
```

To be specific, only this doesn't work:

```
if(year == 0)
{
    year = DateTime.Now.Year;
}

if(month == 0)
{
    month = DateTime.Now.Month;
}
```

Even if I try set year to some value it keeps the default value "0".
It worked like this before but now it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 1**
I figured out, that year and month is locked here becouse it's async action and becouse of this part: `wallet.Expenses = wallet.Expenses.Where(e => e.Date.Month == month && e.Date.Year == year && e.Id == id).ToList();`, but I still don't understand why and how this locking works.

Comment: Please provide the request you are using as well so we can have a better understanding of exactly what the issue might be.

Comment: Post updated. Any ideas?

Comment: *But when i try to change this default values in action to actual date*. How did you do it ?

Comment: When debugger hits
`if(year == 0)
    {
        year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }`
where DateTime.Now.Year returns int, the "year" is not updated and its value = 0.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**http://localhost:xxxx/api/Wallets/16** This would not work as you are passing only one parameter's value that is Id=16 or request would, on its own, consider Id=16.

You need to pass three values.

```
AngularService.GetWallet('http://localhost:xxxx/api/Wallets?id=1&year=2016&month=1').sucess(function(data,status){

}).error(function(data,status){

});
```

or run your localhost. in fiddler client choose get method and pass the same URL **http://localhost:xxxx/api/Wallets?id=1&year=2016&month=1** it will hit the same api with passed values.

or else run localhost. In browser's address bar paste **http://localhost:xxxx/api/Wallets?id=1&year=2016&month=1** it will hit the same api with passed values.

**'But when i try to change this default values in action to actual date it keeps the "0" value'**

Answer : If you try to pass actual date like 1/13/2016, it would not accept it and consider 0 instead as you have int values for all your parameter. You have to take  DateTime datatype for them to work.

Comment: `[Route("{id:int}/{year:int?}/{month:int?}")]`

The question marks in routing means that year and month are optional parameters. This is with purpose - when i don't pass required Date it returns Wallet with Expenses from this month. And I don't try to pass whole Date to the action, only int values for year and month.

The thing is, the default values for year and month cannot be changed to other value int the Action. Its strange behaviour.